# How to set strace output characters string width to be longer?

Tags: strace

Strangely i can't find it any where but when i stdout the output of strace into afile like this:

```
strace foo.exe | & tee foo.log
```

the out put is to short, how can i make the width longer?

Comment: fyi: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`&'`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672743/prevent-strace-from-abbreviating-arguments

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `-s` option under Linux, from the `strace` package, will let you specify the width:

```
-s strsize  Specify  the  maximum  string  size  to  print  (the
            default is 32).  Note that filenames are not consid-
            ered strings and are always printed in full.
```

e.g.

```
strace -s 128 ...
```

Comment: And with colors: `strace $CMD 2>&1 > /dev/null | vim -c ':set syntax=strace' -`.

Answer (score 0):

Use '-o filename' option:

```
  strace -f -o foo.log foo
```

man strace

> -o filename Write the trace output to the file filename

Comment: True, not directly an answer, but I found it useful in this context nonetheless. It does write the full strings into the file.

Comment: Not really, @user63623. I've tried it here and ended up having to use -s anyway (strace 4.26).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point to good directions in general, the specific issue is probably the space you have between "|" and "&". If you're trying to use a bash "|&" to pipe both stdout and stderr you can't have a space between those characters.